# Implement a Resize/Move/Save Visitor Pattern

Tags: c#, winforms, visitor-pattern

I am making a paint program where i can make Rectangle/Ellipse. In that program i can move/resize them but also save them.

My problem is now that i need to make a visitor pattern(Resize/Move and save) But I don't know where i should start.

These are the method i use at the moment:

```
public abstract void ResizeShape(PosSizableRect posSizableRect, float lastX, float lastY, float newX, float newY);
public abstract void MoveShape(int x, int y);
private void Write(List<Shape> shapes, StreamWriter streamWriter, string tabs = "")
```

sorry can't give you pictures because of my reputation...

Comment: so all of your elements have a common supertype? ...

Comment: They all inherit from shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface IShape
{
    void Resize(PosSizableRect posSizableRect, float lastX, float lastY, float newX, float newY);
    void Move(int dx, int dy);
    void Write (StreamWriter writer, string tabs ="");
    void AcceptVisitor(IVisitor visitor);
}

public interface IVisitor
{
    void Visit(IShape shape);
}
```

Thats the interfaces, now the implementation (one example)

```
public class MoveVisitor : IVisitor
{
    private int dx;
    private int dy;

    public MoveVisitor(int dx, int dy)
    {
         this.dx = dx;
         this.dy = dy;
    }
    public void Visit(IShape shape)
    {
         shape.Move(dx,dy);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pklaas however i dont get the sense to use this pattern like this... sense would make to move the implementation of the Command(Move,Rezise) to the visitor. you have more methods for the individual shapes in the interface IVisitor and the concrete implementation of a shape calls its proper one.

Comment: @Pklaas like an Rectangle has x1,y1,x2,y2 and the move implementation would correct all this values with dx and dy, a circle or elipse might have centerX, centerY and the implementation of move would only correct the 2 values.

Comment: Elipse and Rectangle are the same only i draw then different(DrawEllipse() and DrawRectangle()) those two use the same variables